# How to create EditText with menu underneath?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I want to create `EditText` with clickable menu underneath. User should be able to write his own custom text into `EditText` or choose from predefined options.

I though about adding `recyclerView` under `EditText`, but for 4-5 options its waste of `recylerView`. Is there any way to do it better (I dont want to write a lot of code for this feature).

[image]

Comment: Check the tutorial of `AutoCompleteTextView`: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_autocompletetextview_control.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AutoCompleteTextView is a component used to show suggestions while writing in an editable text field. The suggestions list is shown in a drop-down menu from which a user can select the desired item. The list of suggestions is obtained from an adapter and it appears only after a number of characters that are specified in the threshold.

Here is a simple example of AutoCompleteTextView:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
       tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="X" />

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:text="">

            <requestFocus />
        </AutoCompleteTextView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

The MainActivity.java is defined below.

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        String[] animals = {"Ant", "Bbird", "Cat"};

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            //Creating the instance of ArrayAdapter containing list of fruit names
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                    (this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, animals);
            //Getting the instance of AutoCompleteTextView
            AutoCompleteTextView actv = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
            actv.setThreshold(1);//will start working from first character
            actv.setAdapter(adapter);//setting the adapter data into the AutoCompleteTextView
            actv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,
xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="State:" />

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView;
String[] arr={"used","new","repaired"};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    autoCompleteTextView=findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
    ArrayAdapter aa=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arr);
    autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(aa);
}
```

}